# How do I get ANSI bright colors to work in the windows cmd?

Tags: java, cmd, ansi-escape, jline, jansi

I am using java, the jline library and jansi. I have regular colors working just fine, either using `\u001B[32m` for example, or `Ansi.ansi().fg(Ansi.Color.GREEN)`.

However, I cannot seem to get the bright set of colors working. I've tried both `\u001B[92m` or `Ansi.ansi().fgBright(Ansi.Color.GREEN)`.

When I try to use bright colors, I don't see anything strange show up in the console, but the color does not change.

Additional Info:

- I'm on a preview build of windows 10, but I've tried my code on windows server 2012 R2.
- jansi says that ansi is both detected and enabled.
- Issuing `AnsiConsole.systemInstall();` at the beginning does not fix my issue.

One final note: my goal is to be multiplatform.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution! Here's what it looks like jansi requires in order to change between dark and light colors. For example:

`Ansi.ansi().a(Attribute.RESET).fg(Ansi.Color.MAGENTA).boldOff().toString()` Dark Purple
`Ansi.ansi().a(Attribute.RESET).fg(Ansi.Color.MAGENTA).bold().toString()` Light Purple

And so on...